# Curried function defined in terms of its own partial application

Tags: functional-programming, sml, currying, partial-application

The following SML code is taken from a homework assignment from a [course](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/19sp/) at University of Washington. (Specifically it is part of the code provided so that students could use it to complete Homework 3 listed on the [course webpage](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/19sp/).) I am not asking for homework help here–I think I understand what the code is saying. What I don't quite understand is how a curried function is allowed to be defined in terms of its own partial application.

```
 datatype pattern = 
     WildcardP
   | VariableP of string
   | UnitP
   | ConstantP of int
   | ConstructorP of string * pattern
   | TupleP of pattern list

fun g f1 f2 p =
  let 
    val r = g f1 f2      (* Why does this not cause an infinite loop? *)
  in
    case p of
        WildcardP         => f1 ()
      | VariableP x       => f2 x
      | ConstructorP(_,p) => r p
      | TupleP ps         => List.foldl (fn (p,i) => (r p) + i) 0 ps
      | _                 => 0
  end
```

The function binding is a recursive definition that makes use of the recursive structure in the datatype binding for `pattern`. But when we get to the line `val r = g f1 f2`, why doesn't that cause the execution to think, "wait, what is `g f1 f2`? That's what I get by passing `f2` to the function created by passing `f1` to `g`. So let's go back to the definition of `g`" and enter an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lambda calculus abstraction, the curried function `g` is `g = (^f1. (^f2. (^p. ...body...)))` and so

```
g a b = (^f1. (^f2. (^p. ...body...))) a      b 
      =       (^f2. (^p. ...body...)) [a/f1] 
      =             (^p. ...body...)  [a/f1] [b/f2]
```

Partial application just produces the inner lambda function paired with the two parameters bindings closed over -- without entering the body at all.

So defining `r = g f1 f2` is just as if defining it as the lambda function, `r = (^p. g f1 f2 p)` (this, again, is LC-based, so doesn't deal with any of the SML-specific stuff, like types).

And defining a lambda function (a closure) is just a constant-time operation, it doesn't enter the `g` function body, so there is no looping at all, let alone infinite looping.

Answer (score 2):

The function `g` is never recursively called with any value other than `f1` and `f2`. It stands to reason that `g f1 f2` will always have the same result, no matter how many times it is called.

I suggest reading the [Staging](https://smlhelp.github.io/book/concepts/curry.html#staging) section of the section on currying at https://smlhelp.github.io/book/.

A simpler, boiled down example of this same thing in action. A contrived function that counts an int down until a supplied function returns true.

```
fun x (f: int -> bool) (a: int) : int =
  let 
    val g = x f
  in
    if a = 0 then 0
    else if f a then a
    else g (a - 1)  
  end
```

We can see the same translating this to OCaml as well.

```
let rec x f a =
  let g = x f in
  if a = 0 then 0
  else if f a then a
  else g (a - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The body is not evaluated until all arguments are present; `g f1 f2` produces a "closure", a function with one parameter and `f1` and `f2` already bound to their given values.

These are both equivalent, and neither makes it look like there could be an infinite recursion:

You can substitute `r` with its value in the function,

```
fun g f1 f2 p =
    case p of
        WildcardP         => f1 ()
      | VariableP x       => f2 x
      | ConstructorP(_,p) => g f1 f2 p
      | TupleP ps         => List.foldl (fn (p,i) => (g f1 f2 p) + i) 0 ps
      | _                 => 0
```

or "lift" the pattern matching,

```
fun g f1 _ WildCardP = f1 ()
  | g _ f2 (VariableP x) = f2 x
  | g f1 f2 (ConstructorP (_, p)) = g f1 f2 p
  | g f1 f2 (TupleP ps) = List.foldl (fn (p,i) => (g f1 f2 p) + i) 0 ps
  | g _ _ _ = 0
```

Or, you can look at the equivalent "uncurried" function,

```
fun g (f1, f2, p) =
    let 
        val r = fn x => g (f1, f2, x)
    in
        case p of
            WildcardP         => f1 ()
          | VariableP x       => f2 x
          | ConstructorP(_,p) => r p
          | TupleP ps         => List.foldl (fn (p,i) => (r p) + i) 0 ps
          | _                 => 0
    end
```